# Let $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=3$. Then find minimum value of $|z_1+z_2|^2+|z_2+z_3|^2+|z_3+z_1|^2$ is?

Tags: complex-numbers

$$(z_1+z_2)(\bar z_1 +\bar z_2)+(z_2+z_3)(\bar z_2+\bar z_3)+(z_3+z_1)(\bar z_3+\bar z_1)$$
$$=2(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+|z_3|^3) + Re (z1\bar z_2) + Re(z_2\bar z_3)+Re(z_3+\bar z_1)$$

Assuming $z=x+iy$
$$=54 + (x_1x_2+y_1y_2)+(x_2x_3+y_2y_3)+(x_3x_1+y_3y_1)$$

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

that expression is equal to $|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 + |z_3|^2 + |z_1+z_2+z_3|^2 \ge 3 \cdot 3^2 + 0$

Comment: How did you get this?

Comment: parallelogram identity

Comment: The minimum is attained when $z_1+z_2+z_2+z_3 = 0$, i.e. when $z_1,z_2,z_3$ are the vertices of an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 1):

$$|z_1+z_2|^2=(z_1+z_2)(\bar z_1+ \bar z_2)= |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+2 Re (z_1 \bar z_2)$$ $$\Re(Z)<|Z|\implies |z_1+z_2|^2 \le (|z_2|^2+|z_2|^2)+2 |z_1||z_2|=36$$
So $$|z_1+z_2|^2+|z_2+z_3|^2+|z_1+z_3|^2 \le 108.$$

Comment: I am asking the minimum value. The answer is 27